# Moodle - Sent Email Confimation Considered as Spam

Tags: email, moodle, spam, email-spam, email-confirmation

My friend (creating [his project using Moodle](http://technopreneur.fttgraphics.com)) asked me about how to prevent/exclude the sent email confirmation from his Moodle project to being classified as spam on new user's email.

I cannot answer him because i am not that great with Moodle.

Can anyone here help him?

Answers will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with programming...

Answer (score 2):

Your moodle installation, technopreneur.fttgraphics.com, is a subdomain

Add this line to the end of config.php

- If you using **SUBDOMAIN**: `$CFG->maildomain = 'technopreneur.fttgraphics.com';`
- If you using **DIRECTORIES**: `$CFG->maildomain = 'http://domain.cz/folder_of_moodle';`

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has an email server he should look to configurate Moodle to use SMTP authentication (Site administration > Message outputs > Email). 
Doc : https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Messaging_settings#Email

If he does not have an email server he could add a SPF entry in his DNS zone.